# iOS get current address name - mkplacemark?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, mkplacemark

I was wondering how to get users current address name. I've alread found its coordinates but I need to find the name of the user's current city. Is it better to use Google APIs or should I use MKPlacemark to find it? I saw that the MKReverseGeocoding is deprecated in iOS 5.0. Please help with some simple tutorial or just your experience.

Answer (score 3):

I am user whatever approach you use , all you are interested is in finding the location details.

You can use multiple approaches depending upon what gets you the desired result.

1] Try MKReverseGeocoder (however The MapKit framework uses Google services to provide map data.)

2] You can use Google API to fetch the result.

If you are getting MKReverseGeocoder deprecated ypu can use CLGeocoder.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks,NSError *error)
         {
             if([placemarks count]>0){
                 CLPlacemark *result=[placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                 NSString *city=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result locality]];
}
];
```